# How can I connect my php database to my android application without it crashing?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I downloaded sample code trying to test it out but I cannot connect it to my hosted database properly. My app just crashes when I try to load it. I looked over my logcat but cannot make sense of it.

My Logcat:

```
07-30 22:39:00.702: D/AndroidRuntime(23520): Shutting down VM
07-30 22:39:00.702: W/dalvikvm(23520): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4194ada0)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520): Process: selva.select, PID: 23520
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at selva.select.DbselectActivity$1.onClick(DbselectActivity.java:88)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-30 22:39:00.702: E/AndroidRuntime(23520):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 22:39:03.194: I/Process(23520): Sending signal. PID: 23520 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity:

```
package selva.select;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;

public class DbselectActivity extends Activity
{
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View view) 
              {
                String result = null;
                InputStream is = null;

                try{
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("drinkdealsapplicationdublin.net78.net/selectall.php");
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();

                        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                //convert response to string
                try
                {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result=sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                //parse json data
                try
                {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    String re=jArray.getString(jArray.length()-1);
                    TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
                    tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                    int flag=1;

                    for(int i=-1;i<jArray.length()-1;i++)
                        {
                                TableRow tr=new TableRow(DbselectActivity.this);
                                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                                if(flag==1)
                                {
                                    TextView b6=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    b6.setText("ID");
                                    b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                    b6.setTextSize(15);
                                    tr.addView(b6);

                                    TextView b19=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                    b19.setTextSize(15);
                                    b19.setText("Name");
                                    b19.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                    tr.addView(b19);

                                    TextView b29=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                    b29.setText("no");
                                    b29.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                    b29.setTextSize(15);
                                    tr.addView(b29);

                                    tv.addView(tr);

                                    final View vline = new View(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
                                    vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                                    tv.addView(vline);
                                    flag=0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("f1")+
                                            ", Username: "+json_data.getString("f2")+
                                            ", No: "+json_data.getInt("f3"));


                                    TextView b=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    String stime=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("f1"));
                                    b.setText(stime);
                                    b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                    b.setTextSize(15);
                                    tr.addView(b);                          

                                    TextView b1=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                    b1.setTextSize(15);
                                    String stime1=json_data.getString("f2");
                                    b1.setText(stime1);
                                    b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tr.addView(b1);

                                    TextView b2=new TextView(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                    String stime2=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("f3"));
                                    b2.setText(stime2);
                                    b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                    b2.setTextSize(15);
                                    tr.addView(b2);

                                    tv.addView(tr);

                                    final View vline1 = new View(DbselectActivity.this);
                                    vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                                    vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tv.addView(vline1);
                                }
                       }
                }
                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
           }
        });
     }
}
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php  

$con = mysql_connect('XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX');
if (!$con)
{
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("a9588589_drink", $con);        

$i=mysql_query("select * from t1",$con);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($i);

$check='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($i))
{
    $r[]=$row;
    $check=$row['f1'];
}

if($check==NULL)
{            
    $r[$num_rows]="Record is not available";
    print(json_encode($r));
}
else
{
    $r[$num_rows]="success";
    print(json_encode($r));
} 
 mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Link to PHP Script: http://drinkdealsapplicationdublin.net78.net/selectall.php
I don't think I need to include anything else but I got the tutorial from http://androidprogramz.blogspot.ie/2012/07/retrieve-database-from-mysql-and.html
Apologies if I left anything out and thanks for your time.

Also, incase you need it the XML file:
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/e1"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true">

            <TableLayout 
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true">

            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

edit: More info: When I click the button to load the data, it crashes then. The app starts

Comment: Null pointer at selva.select.DbselectActivity$1.onClick(DbselectActivity.java:88). What is on line 88?

Comment: JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

Comment: Then I would think that the toast saying 'Input reading fail' should be shown, cause it seems result is null then. In either case, I think merging the two try-catch statements would be a good idea to avoid trying to use the result variable in case the first try-catch block fails

Comment: @user3849188 I tried to make your code a bit easier to follow; by reducing the amount of scrolling from large numbers of blank lines and by making all the code within a block at the same level of indent.  THe java however still has a lot of room for improvement.  1) Tabs or spaces.  Pick one.  Either work, but a mix of the two is always a mess.  2)  Pick a consistent level of indenting per block.  I didn't mess with this because it was impossible to tell what your intent was.  In Java 4 spaces/1 (4 space) tab is the most commonly used format.

Comment: Also, the mysql_ functions in PHP are unsafe to use and have been deprecated.  Unless you want your site to get hacked, you need to use a safe way to access the database instead.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. Ill look into all your suggestions thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I tried replacing the code but I'm getting an error saying Syntax error on token "package", import expected beside the package in the main class. The package location is right as well

Comment: never mind I fixed that problem! Now to fix the main one

Comment: See http response and status first response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()<--status                           EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())